# Can't insert null

Tags: oracle, forms, plsql

The problem is that I have a form where I insert services into each record by entering service code. Services exist in a table called t_services. When I insert a service and save it, it is inserted in another table called s_services(my block).

If I'm inserting a service that doesn't exist an exception will be thrown.
Then I try to save after I've undone the service that doesn't exist but a message shows telling me that I can't insert a null value.

I know that because the service is a primary key, but why can't I save even if the record is null while the cursor is still on the record that I don't want to add a value to it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your code? Then your question gets faster answered becasue people understand it better. :-)

Comment: Select t_s_code,t_s_desc into :s_code,:s_desc from t_services where t_s_code =:s_code exception WHEN OTHERS THEN raise_application_error (-20002,'code not exist') ; i write it ins_code item when validate trigger on ..

Comment: "I try to save after I've undone the service that doesn't exist". Sounds like you're not doing the clean-up properly. But a better approach would be to be proactive: present the user with a list of available service codes from `t_services` and allow them to add new codes there before populating data in `s_services` block.